# Importing jabref xml reference file for Microsoft word on PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, xml, microsoft-word

I manged to successfully install Microsoft Word on PlayOnlinux. I use `jabref` for references which can generate an XML file which can be imported into word for citation. I can do this on word on MS Windows but not on Ubuntu.

In word, i click on the references tab. Click on manged resources;click on the browse button to select the xml file. I do all this but the master list shows as empty.

Maybe i should run jabref in wine or PlayOnlinux, would this help?

Comment: You mean "browse" as in "use a browser to view the contents"? That will always display an XML file as empty. But if you view the source, you will see that it is not empty after all. Or do you mean "open the XML file with Word"?

Comment: In word, i click on the references tab. Click on manged resources;click on the browse button to select the xml file. I do all this but the master list shows as empty.